# Delphi XE5 FireMonkey Transfer File

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey

I am writing an application in FireMonkey for XE5 running on an Android Tablet (and eventually also an IPad mini)

As one it's functions, I need to be able to take a photograph on the tablet and then transfer that back to a database on a PC. I have got the part to take the photograph and save it on the tablet working fine, but I am struggling to know how to get that onto A PC

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to get it back to the PC via syncing the tablet, or by network transfer (internet or local network) immediately once the photo is taken, or...?

Comment: I'd like to do it by internet transfer. I already have a database on a server which I am accessing using UniDac via WiFi, so that would seem the logical way to do it.

Comment: @PaulJones : `I'd like to do it by internet transfer` : so what's stopping you from doing it in this way ?

Comment: Then search StackOverflow for http client and httpserver libraries for Delphi.

Comment: Or use any syncing service. Dropbox has a dedicated API, Yandex Disk uses standard http+tls+webdav, Google drive uses something too... And there a lot of others